python swifter rolling() runtime error "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'"
When I'm running rolling() with swifter like below, I get a runtime error "init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'".
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import swifter

t = np.arange("1900-01-01", "2019-12-25", dtype=np.datetime64)
np.random.seed(seed=0)
y = np.random.rand(len(t))
df_pd = pd.DataFrame({"t": t, "y": y})
df_pd.head()

df_pd.swifter.set_npartitions(npartitions=8).progress_bar(True).rolling(5).apply(np.mean)

pandas version 2.2.2 
swifter version 1.4.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\owner\source\repos\PythonApplication7\PythonApplication7\PythonApplication7.py", line 27, in <module>
    df_pd.swifter.set_npartitions(npartitions=8).progress_bar(True).rolling(5).apply(np.mean)
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\swifter\swifter.py", line 162, in rolling
    return Rolling(
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\swifter\swifter.py", line 737, in __init__
    self._obj_dd = self._obj_dd.rolling(**{k: v for k, v in kwds.items() if k not in ["on", "closed"]})
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\dask_expr\_collection.py", line 974, in rolling
    return Rolling(self, window, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'


This seems to be a problem in the swifter source code. At present, swifter.rolling passes an "axis" kwarg to its Dask counterpart. This kwarg is no longer valid in the Dask implementation, as it was deprecated with pandas>=2.1, so any call to swifter.rolling is guaranteed to raise an error.
I don't know of any proper workaround at present, though I've opened an issue on GitHub.
